# Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server

Tags: permissions, ntfs, share, file-server

I have a folder A and inside two files B and C

What I need is that the user "XPTO" as access to read B and write on C.

Usually I give the permission "list folder contents" on folder and then give a write access on the file for the user and then I create a shortcut on desktop.

What is happening now is that if I give write permission on Folder the user can write on the file if I just give read permission on folder he is not allow to make change on the file even if a change the file permissions and give write permissions only on that file. I already test disabling inheritance and keep in the same way.

Comment: What do you have configured for the Share permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is enabled by default. You would approach a situation like that as following:

1. Open the folder's Security Settings.
   [image]
2. Add the user to the list. By default *Allow* is checked for *Read*, *List Folder Contents* and *Read & Execute*.
3. Click OK and close the window.
4. Open the Security Settings for file *C*.
5. The user should already be listed as the file inherits the folders security settings. Select the user and click on *Allow* *Modify*.
6. Click OK and close the window.

Done.